# Runtime of Recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, relation, recurrence, master-theorem

Just had this on a quiz: T(n) = 4T(sqrt(n)) + 5

I simplified it using substitution and got F(k) = 4F(k/2) + 5

Using the master theorem I guessed it was O(logn). Is this accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

```
F(n) = T(2^n)
```

Then we have that

```
F(n) = 4F(n/2) + 5
```

By the master theorem, we have that

```
a = 4
b = 2
f(n) = 5 = O(1) = O(m^0), so c = 0
0 < 2 = log_2(4)
```

So we're in case 1 of the master theorem. By case 1, we have

```
F(n) = Theta(n^2)
```

So

```
T(2^n) = Theta(n^2)
```

Therefore

```
T(n) = Theta(log(n^2)) = Theta(2logn) = Theta(log n)
```

So yes, your answer seems to be correct.